dataTable paging and inline field edit
I wonder, why inline field edit works on a first dataTable page only, even if below code applies the ".crm-editable" class to all table cells.
  CRM.$('#options').DataTable({
  "bFilter": true,
  "iDisplayLength": 15,
  "bDeferRender": true,
  "bPaginate": true,
  "bSortClasses": true,
    rowCallback: function ( row, data, index ) {      
     CRM.$('td:eq(4)', row).addClass('crm-editable');
  }, 
});

UPD Have tried the SearchKit, however it doesn't seem to allow inline edit:  https://i.sstatic.net/8HfIfpTK.png

DataTables is now deprecated in favor of SearchKit. Is it possible for you to achieve your goal using a SearchKit display instead?

@Coleman Not quite sure SearchKit allows inline edit.

Yes it does. You can configure it in the Search Display.

@Coleman Thank you! These modern toys are so complex..

DataTables are deprecated, but
you can configure a SearchKit display with inline edit.
